# Is there a way to make recurrsive change to pandas.shift()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been trying to do update data by lookback at its previous and update it with the previous one if previous row values is higher. So here's what I did:

```
the data: df['stock_available']
prev_row = df['stock_available'].shift(1)
update:
df['stock_available'] = np.where(prev_row>df['stock_available'], prev_row, df['stock_available'])
```

It doesn't work because the prev_row doesn't update accordingly.
Please help.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the dataframe (`df.head().to_dict()`) and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with

```
df['Column2'] = df.Column1.shift(1).fillna(0.0)
df['Column1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Column2'] if x['Column2'] > x['Column1'] else x['Column1'], axis=1)
df= df.drop('Column2', axis=1)
```